# HTTP fetch failed from 'test-service': error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I am getting below error when we are updating new deployment in k8s, after 30-45 seconds connection is working fine with other micro-service.

HTTP fetch failed from 'test-service': error trying to connect: tcp connect error: Connection refused (os error 111)

AKS Version : 1.24.6

Answer (score 0):

The error may occur due to many reasons, one of the main reasons is networking issues with your server. Connection refused means that the port you are trying to connect to is not actually open.

**Try below troubleshooting steps to resolve your error**:

- Check whether you are connecting to the correct IP address, or to the wrong port, or the server is listening on the wrong port, or is not actually running.
- A common mistake is not specifying the port number when binding or connecting in network byte order.
- Validate that you have enabled Direct Connection Access.
- Check if your service is responding to http port. Maybe you could do a port-forward from your pod to your desktop local. Replace the values pod_name, pod_port and local_port in the command below.

> `kubectl port-forward <pod_name> <local_port>:<pod_port>`

- Try connecting to the Kubernetes Worker host and do the diagnosis there, since from the hosts point of view, the container is only a process.

Refer to this [gitlink](https://github.com/LukeChannings/moviematch/issues/51) for more information about the error.